# Issues with pushing to detail view when cell is tapped

Tags: swift

I have just added a detail view for my cells and I am having issues with being unable to select a cell to push to the detail view.

For some reason, when I tap one of the cells normally, nothing happens. However when I tap one of the cells after performing a search, the cell pushes to the detail view. I have looked through all of my code but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Initially I thought it was this line:

```
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

But I commented it out and it didn't make a difference.

Here is the relevant code (Sorry for the length!):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
    if names.count == 0 {
        if enterButtonTapped == false {
            backgroundLabel.text = "Before you add any transactions, you must first set a budget. You can do this by tapping the 'Budget' tab."
        } else {
            backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        }
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()
        backgroundLabel.hidden = false
        backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        clearButton.enabled = false

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        return 0
    } else {
        backgroundLabel.hidden = true
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        clearButton.enabled = true
        return names.count
    }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell
    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
        //println(searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
        var indexValue = names.indexOfObject(searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }
        //This works, unless there are two payments with the same name. To revert to previous version, remove tableView if statement and just keep code below the else.
    } else {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (names.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        if let tv=tableView {
            if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
                UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
            } else {
            var valueToRemove: AnyObject! = unformatted.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            //println(valueToRemove)

            if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
                totalSpendingsCounter = totalSpendingsCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalSpendingsCounter, forKey: "spendingsCounter")
            } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
                totalCreditCounter = totalCreditCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalCreditCounter, forKey: "creditCounter")
            }

            currencyDouble = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("currencyCounter")
            currentBudgetCalculation = currencyDouble + totalCreditCounter - totalSpendingsCounter

            newTransactionEntered = true

            var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
            formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // This is the default
            var formattedNumberCurrent = formatter.stringFromNumber(currentBudgetCalculation)

            var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
            defaults.setObject(formattedNumberCurrent, forKey: "currentBudgetWidget")
            defaults.setObject(newTransactionEntered, forKey: "new")

            values.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            images.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            names.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            dates.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            unformatted.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(names, forKey: "names")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(values, forKey: "values")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dates, forKey: "dates")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(unformatted, forKey: "unformatted")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(images, forKey: "images")

            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    self.presentViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why are you presenting the detail view in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Ah, that was a mistake. It didn't fix the issue, but it should have been didSelectRowAtIndexPath.